# Ubuntu server config remote access

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh

I did a fresh clean install of Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS with out anything on it. First thing I want to set up after the installation is remote access. So I did:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
```

Despite this I am still unable to remotely access my server with this command from terminal:

```
ssh name@ip
```

Just wonted to underline this is the first time am doing it and my first interaction with Ubuntu server so this question might be lame.

Comment: Is there an error message? if so, please [edit] your question to include it

Comment: nope no error the installation of ssh was sucesfull, but I think i might need some cofigurations...?

Comment: So what exactly happens when you type `ssh name@ip`?

Comment: after a long while of waiting the terminal outputs: ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx port xx: Operation timed out

Comment: run this command `ssh -E ~/sshLog.txt name@ip` and provide the output of `cat ~/sshLog.txt`

Comment: Warning: Permantley added 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (ECDSA) to the list ok knows hosts.

Comment: I runned these commands on mu server they did not obviousley i guess work from my remote terminal

Comment: @Tomazi reboot your server

Comment: just did still the same, is there any confi required on my server after installing openssh-server openssh-client ?

Comment: @Tomazi no theres not. show us your config file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` can you ping your server.  and have you tried disabling the firewall maybe its blocking the ssh port. `sudo ufw disable`

Comment: hmmm I can ping out of my server, but when i ping my server i get request time out 100% packet loss. My ubuntu server in on virtualbox can this possibly have any impact?

Comment: also when i ping koper which is my hostname i belief: koper@ubuntu the ping works, but when i ping xx.xx.xx.xx it fails, this would suggest there is a problem with dns?

Answer (score 0):

You have not configured your ssh config file. 
You need to generate the `ssh` keys using the command
`ssh-keygen`

Then you need to add the user name of the remote server by adding the user in ssh config file.
 For detailed information you can try this link

Answer (score 0):

OK guys thanks for all your help, I did find the problem after lots of research etc, I did some diagnostic like route, routetrace that the ip 10.0.2.15 was wired and was not my network ip, anyway this had led me to suspect something may be wrong with my virtualbox its self. So I checked the network configs for my ubuntu server box and noticed it was atached to NAT changed this Bridged Adapter and that was it it works :)